# Constructing pytorch Dataset class, returns 'tuple' object has no attribute 'iloc' on iterating

Tags: python, oop, pytorch

I was learning how to prepare dataset for BERT's question-answering model ([click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_l2wJb3QPdk&t=1207s) for the video). When I was creating the BioQADataSet class with the help of pytorch's Dataset class, in goolge's colab, I get an AttributeError, when I try to print a row with the help of **getitem** method. (The BioQA Dataset is for training Question-Answering BERT model. The column contains ID, question, context, answer_text, answer_start-> the start index, answer_end-> the end index). The following code represents the BioQADataSet class:

```
class BioQADataSet(Dataset):
      def __init__(self, data:pd.DataFrame, tokenizer: T5Tokenizer,source_max_token_len:int = 512, target_max_token_len: int = 32):
        self.data = data,
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer,
        self.source_max_token_len = source_max_token_len,
    self.target_max_token_len = target_max_token_len

def __len__(self):
    return len(self.data)

def __getitem__(self, index: int):

    data_row = self.data.iloc[index]

    source_encoding = tokenizer(
      sample_question['question'],
      sample_question["context"],
      max_length = self.source_max_token_len,
      padding = 'max_length',
      truncation = "only_second",
      return_attention_mask = True,
      add_special_tokens = True,
      return_tensors = 'pt'
    )

    target_encoding = tokenizer(
      sample_question['answer_text'],
      max_length = self.target_max_token_len,
      padding = 'max_length',
      truncation = True,
      return_attention_mask = True,
      add_special_tokens = True,
      return_tensors = 'pt'
    )
    labels = target_encoding["input_ids"]
    labels[labels==0]= -100

    return dict(
        question = data_row["question"],
        context = data_row['context'],
        answer = data_row['answer_text'],
        input_ids = source_encoding["input_ids"].flatten(),
        attention_mask = source_encoding['attention_mask'].flatten(),
        labels = labels.flatten()
    )


for data in sample_dataset:
  print(data)
  break
```

[image]

Is there any problem with my code? I can't identify my mistake.

Comment: Hi, you should always copy-and-paste the stacktrace into your question as a code block, rather than inserting an image. Doing so makes it easier for people to copy-and-paste if they need to, and also makes it accessible to those using screen readers.

Comment: That said, I suspect you need to change `self.data.iloc[index]` to just `self.data[index]`. Tuples can be indexed directly; `.iloc()` is for things like dataframes.

Comment: [1] I'll make sure of that. [2] I tried changing it to self.data[index] but no help. It is giving: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'tuple'

Answer (score 0):

Changing
`data_row = self.data.iloc[index]` to
`data_row = self.data.iloc[[index]].to_dict('records')[0]`
will do the trick.